# Disabling the auto move of windows to the primary screen when changing screen configuration?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, win32

Using a single screen machine when I log in via Remote Desktop to a machine with three screens, all my open windows automatically get moved to the primary screen.

Is there a way to disable this functionality, either through the registry or programmatically? I want all the windows to always stay in the same positions even if they would be off screen.

This also happens if you change the display configuration, i.e. move from three screens to one screen.

Comment: Some thoughts : (1) While connecting specify the option of Display / Use all my monitors for the remote session, (2) Use `mstsc /span` to connect.

Comment: I am moving from 3 screens to a single screen so that will not work.

Comment: Are the 3 screens on the local or remote computer ?

Comment: 3 screens are on local and one on remote